# My code doesn't get executed when I remove debug.print in VBA

Tags: vba

My code skips this loop completely when I remove the debug.print line.

```
For i = 2 To RowCount         
   temp1 = 0
   temp1 = InStr(Range("A" & i), "rj")
   If temp1 > 0 Then
      Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
      Debug.Print i
      i = i - 1
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: What's the value of RowCount if thats a variable if you want the last row it's Rows.Count

Comment: Also start the loop from last row to the startrow since you are deleting rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim lstRow As Long
lstRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row

For i = lstRow To 2 Step -1          
  If InStr(Range("A" & i), "rj") > 0 Then
      Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next i
```